# Getting td totals based on class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamically generated table which looks something like this:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td class="col2">1</td>
            <td class="col3">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td class="col2">7</td>
            <td class="col3">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td class="col2">col2</td>
            <td class="col3">col3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Totals</td>
            <td id="col2total"></td>
            <td id="col3total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

How do I get the total of the values in the `td`s which have the class `col2` and add the total to the `td` with the id `col2total`?  As this table is dynamically generated, I will not know how many `tr`'s are generated in the `tbody`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var total = 0;
$(".col2").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat('0' + $(this).text(), 10);
})
$("#col2total").text(total);
```

Comment: I suggest: `parseFloat('0' + $(this).text(), 10);` so that non-numeric values end up as zero.

Comment: @Ariel a nice simple method, I've updated the answer - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;
$("td.col2").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0;
});

$("#col2total").text(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var sum = 0; 
    $('.col2').each(function() { 
        sum += Number($(this).val()); 
    });

    $("#col2total").text(sum); 
});
```